Calculating predicted probabilities from Lavaan with categorical outcome using DWLS estimator
I am Interested in estimating a structural equation model using LAVAAN in R with a categorical outcome and am trying to understand the process of generating predicted probabilities for that outcome based on the model. My understanding is that with Categorical data lavaan uses the WLSMV estimator and the regression coefficients in the model are probit regression coefficients.
Let’s say the outcome of interest has three variables predicting it, x1, x2, x3, with three associated probit coeffients B1, B2, B3. My understanding is the intercept would be fixed to zero by default in lavaan. I could therefore work out the probabilities as I would with probit regression as follows: F(x1B1 + x2+B2 + x3B3) and F is the CDF of the standard normal distribution. I could then convert this into a probability using, for example the norm.s.dist function in excel (=norm.s.dist(F, TRUE)).
I hope this is clear, I am just trying to understand the process of how I might generate predicted probabilities for a given outcome in this sort of model.

In principle, it is possible to manually calculate predicted probabilities for particular combinations of predictor values in the way you describe.  The normal CDF is available in R using the pnorm() function.  But lavaan isn't set up for casewise prediction.  Using the glm() function facilitates this more easily, using the predict() method.
